# Working around globalization issues when executing T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In an app, where SQL server databases with schemas and locale unknown at compile-time (determined at runtime) can be plugged in, I need to figure out how to update a decimal field - ie. what decimal separator to use.

So against one server, if I need to update a decimal field, I would send 100.125. On another server that would be interpreted as 100,125.

I use oldschool SqlCommand-class to do so, since I do not know the schema at compile-time.

At runtime, can I determine which separator I should use? Or is there another way of handling this, that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some discussion on that issue [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2006/10/24/15172.aspx#36434).

Can you supply some context to your query why just using a dot wouldn't work?

As far as I understand it

```
UPDATE tbl SET Col = 1.23
```

would work anywhere and you would only get problems if you did

```
UPDATE tbl SET Col = '1.23'
```